# How do I assign a value to a random subset of a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to select a random subset of a `pd.DataFrame` and set a value to a certain column. Here's a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'species': ['platypus', 'monkey', 'possum'],
    'name': ['mike', 'paul', 'doug'],
    'group': ['control', 'control', 'control']
})
```

```
    species  name    group
0  platypus  mike  control
1    monkey  paul  control
2    possum  doug  control
```

I tried the follow, to randomly assign two people to the experimental group, but it won't work:

```
df.sample(2)['group'] = 'experimental'
```

This won't work either, in fact:

```
df.iloc[[0, 1]]['group'] = 'experimental'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `df.sample(2).index` to get the indexes in your df of the randomly sampled data, you can then pass this into `.loc` to set the group column for those indexes to be 'experimental' as below:

```
df.loc[df.sample(2).index, 'group'] = 'experimental'
```

Output:

```
    species  name         group
0  platypus  mike  experimental
1    monkey  paul  experimental
2    possum  doug       control
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that picks random indexes, random number of times.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

def custom_randomizer(df, col):
    
    total_randoms = random.choice(df.index) + 1
    for _ in range(total_randoms):
        df.loc[random.choice(df.index), col] = 'expiremental'
    
    return df
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'species': ['platypus', 'monkey', 'possum'],
    'name': ['mike', 'paul', 'doug'],
    'group': ['control', 'control', 'control']
})

df = custom_randomizer(df, 'group')

print(df)
```

Comment: doesn't this have the potential to replace twice the same value and therefore won't necessarily perform `n` replacements?

Comment: @NicolasGervais Yes, that's part of being random. Otherwise you have to extract N random choices from the list and replace them.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['group'].iloc[[0, 1]] = 'experimental'
```

Output

```
    species  name         group
0  platypus  mike  experimental
1    monkey  paul  experimental
2    possum  doug       control
```